# Each time point is from a different sample

Tags: granger-causality

I have a question about Granger causality with a specific dataset.

Let's say I give 50 mice some treatment and I am interested in seeing how gene expression in the heart changes over 5 days. Since I have to harvest the heart in order to test gene expression, I test it in 10 mice every day.

Now I don't have a true time series because the genes measured on day 1 are from a different sample of mice than genes measured from day 2.

Can I still do Granger Causality on this dataset? Can I just take the mean expression at each day?

Thank You!

Vitaly